# Installing Xamarin for Visual Studio totally offline

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, offline

I want to develop Android apps using C# with Xamarin in Visual Studio.
However, they provide an installer which will download required files only. How can I download a full offline (incl. its requirements) installer?

I have the following software already installed:
- Java  8u101
- Java SE Development Kit 8u91
- .NET Framework 4.6 with SDK
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express (I don't know if Xamarin will work with this - please let me know)
- Android SDK (installed earlier for Android Studio)

If you know where I can download an offline installer for Xamarin.Android, please let me know. I cannot download through the Universal Installer since I have a poor connection.

I apologize if I have posted in the wrong place.

Thank you

Update: i have VS 2015 ENTERPRISE EDITION

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Comment: VS2010 Express does not support plugins, Xamarin will not work with it.  You can use VS2015 Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log in to your Xamarin account page and go to the downloads section [1].

You'll be able to get everything you need for an offline install if you click the "Show all versions" link underneath the large blue button.

Grab the Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android Windows installer (they're the same thing) - that's it!

Seeing as you need Visual Studio 2015 (as you have 2010 and Xamarin is not compatible with 2010 anymore), you can also grab a copy of the VS 2015 Community ISO [2].

[1] https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads
[2] https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146

Comment: thankyou bro for quick answer, i gonna try it but i didn't see sign up button on Xamarin's website.

Comment: You can use this magic xml file without login : https://xampubdl.blob.core.windows.net/static/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

If You want to install it by Visual Studio installer:
Try download it manually. View file Catalog.json at installation root. Find string containing "Xamarin.VisualStudio":

{"id":"Xamarin.VisualStudio","version":"4.6.3.4","type":"Vsix","payloads":[{"fileName":"Xamarin.VisualStudio.vsix","sha256":"c082f47bc00da4420cd1e90f167ad4285688b5c5df1d115c5dda1f1ec2aa1ffb","size":492545242,"url":"https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/11327837/d68d54e233c956ff79799fdf63753c54/Xamarin.VisualStudio.vsix"}],"vsixId":"Xamarin.VisualStudio",

here

4.6.3.4 - version of Xamarin;

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/11327837/d68d54e233c956ff79799fdf63753c54/Xamarin.VisualStudio.vsix - try download this file, then check file size and checksum, here sha256.

If all ok, change file name to "Xamarin.VisualStudio.vsix" and put it to folder at root of instalation, and name it using id and version, here :

Xamarin.VisualStudio,version=4.6.3.4

Answer (score -1):

1. Please check here 
   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quick-start-tutorial-manual-or-quick-way-of-xamarin-and-simulator-installation/
2. No Idea Microsoft Visual studio 2010 express is support Instead of use 
   Visual Studio Community 2015 its free

Comment: ofc, i have vs 2015 enterprise too.

Comment: go ahead VS2015 enterprise also should support Please find the VS difference here https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/